# Pass custom function with arguments to R terra roll() function

Tags: r, terra

I am trying to use the `terra::roll()` function to compute a rolling geometric mean.  I created another function to calculate the geometric mean, but that function has arguments I would like to pass through.  See reprex below, how do I make a function that `roll()` can call and pass additional args to it?

Thanks

```r
# geomean function with arguments
geomean <- function(v, floor = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE){
  exp(sum(log(v[v > floor]), na.rm=na.rm) / length(v))
}

# outer function for rolling geomean
rollgm <- function(x, N = 30, type = 'to', ...) {
  terra::roll(as.vector(x), N, geomean, type = type, ...)  # ... should be passed to geomean()
}

# example
d <- c(runif(10), NA, NA, runif(10))
rollgm(d, N=5, type = 'to', floor = 0.5)  # error unused argument floor
# how to pass through the floor argument ?
```

Comment: I haven't but ultimately I am trying to use this inside a `stars::st_apply()` function like:  `st_apply(star_object, c("x", "y"), rollgm, floor = 10, N = 30)` and I don't think stars will work with the SpatRaster.  I'm using terra over raster too b/c it's newer and a bit faster as well.

Comment: [ellipsis](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/02/r-three-dots-ellipsis/), don't know that this helps, but appears you''ll want to define what those `...` are in a list, such that `...` knows, in advance, it means `floor`. Stick with `terra`. I was suggesting SpatRast because it has `...`, but those are meant for writing out, again, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `roll` does not pass the arguments in `...` to the function specified in the `fun` argument (see [terra::roll source code](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/R/roll.R)). However, you could define `geomean` inside the outer function using the passed arguments as default values:

```
# outer function for rolling geomean
rollgm <- function(x, N = 30, type = 'to', gm.floor = 0.1, gm.na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  
  # define inside outer function with specified arguments
  # note that 'floor = floor' would cause an error (recursive default argument reference), 
  # hence the 'gm.' prefix
  geomean <- function(v, floor = gm.floor, na.rm = gm.na.rm){
    exp(sum(log(v[v > floor]), na.rm = na.rm) / length(v))
  }
  
  # help(terra::roll):  ... additional arguments for writing files as in writeRaster
  terra::roll(x = as.vector(x), n = N, fun = geomean, type = type, ...)
}

# example
d <- c(runif(10), NA, NA, runif(10))
rollgm(d, N = 5, type = 'to', gm.floor = 0.5)  # no error
rollgm(d, N = 5, type = 'to', gm.floor = 0.5, gm.na.rm = FALSE)  # no error
```

Comment: Thanks Julian, I think that does it!  The only thing I changed was to remove the ... from the call to `terra::roll()` because as you state, I don't think that has any bearing on the call to the inner geomean function.